# Weird UIView rendering issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I'm facing a really weird problem with a UIView (as seen in the attached screenshot).

Basically there is a UIView with a backgroundColor that has an alpha of 0.9 (the dark blue area). Within that view there is some text, and another UIView (the circle). I've got an NSTimer that runs every second to count down that middle number (16), however for some reason, after about 3 seconds the dark blue area becomes 100% transparent (only in certain areas, e.g. the light blue with dots, and the 'records' section) and shows the UI elements in a completely different view. If I remove the alpha transparency on the backgroundColor, everything continues to render correctly and this issue doesn't occur.

Any suggestions? I've tried forcing it to redraw the UIView, tried adding another UIView and setting the background of that as well.

[image]

EDIT: It's also occurring with a 3rd party library not written by me (the alert window).
[image]

Comment: Post the method that is being called every second. It has to be in there.

Comment: That was my thought too, commenting out the timeLabel.text line prevents the issue from occurring... It's just an NSTimer, and within the timer I call `timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.f", self.time];`. Commenting that out causes the problem to go away. It's almost as if anything that is drawn or modified in the view afterwards causes the issue.

Comment: On further investigation, it appears to be any UIView added to `[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow`

Answer (score 1):

Add an assert in your timer handling method to insure you are on the main thread when you deal with the UI (see NSThread).

Also why are you adding views to the key window and not to your root view? The system moves windows in the Z plane.